# Segmentation fault through mutable references

Tags: rust, segmentation-fault

I've been experimenting with some unsafe code, and just recently hit an interesting observation. The following code creates some values and stores them in a vector. It also creates raw pointers which point to the values. Later on, it attempts to read the values again by using the pointers. This results in a segmentation fault in the second loop:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut values = vec![];
    let mut pointers = vec![];
    for i in 0..1_000_000 {
        values.push(i);
        pointers.push(values.last_mut().unwrap() as *mut usize);

        let value = unsafe { &mut **pointers.get_mut(i).unwrap() };
        if value == &0 {
            // This line just exists to make sure the compiler does not optimize the check away
            println!("0");
        }
    }

    println!("first loop finished");

    // Same logic as in the lower part of the first loop, just in another loop
    for i in 0..1_000_000 {
        let value = unsafe { &mut **pointers.get_mut(i).unwrap() };
        if value == &0 {
            println!("0");
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
0
first loop finished
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What I find interesting about this is that

- it results in a segmentation fault at all
- the segmentation fault only happens in the second loop, the first one runs without a problem
- the segmentation fault seems to occur at a random iteration in the second loop, not at the same one every time

I'd be interested in what Rust is doing under the hood for this situation to happen. I know that *multiple mutable references are undefined behaviour*, but what exactly happens here for a segmentation fault to occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior since it accesses memory after it has been freed.

A vector does not immediately have space for all 1,000,000 elements; it will grow exponentially when `.push()`-ing a value beyond its capacity. When this happens it will allocate a new region of memory, move existing elements over, and deallocate the previous region of memory. **This means any pointer to the prior elements are now invalid** since the data no longer exists at that address.

Your first loop does not encounter this error because `values` is not modified after getting a pointer to `values[i]` and printing it with `pointers[i]`. So you know `pointer[i]` is still valid, but all previous pointers `0..i` may not be.

When or where you get a segmentaion fault is not defined, you may trigger one on the first invalid access, or may not trigger it at all! This is pretty much what "undefined behavior" means. You can fix your problem by initializing the `values` vector with a pre-set allocation size: [`Vec::with_capacity()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! While thinking about this further I realized that the vector might allocate different memory during the iterations, and so I updated my question to use a `HashMap`. It seems a `HashMap` does the same thing however.

Comment: @Bobface you may get different behavior with different containers because some have stable addresses for their elements (see [`LinkedList`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html) for example), but I believe the current `HashMap` implementation keeps elements in a single allocation and thus would also move elements on resizing just like a `Vec`.

Answer (score 2):

That illustrates perfectly the kind of *unsafety* Rust prevents us from.

In your first loop you memorise the address of each integer but at each iteration the vector grows and may decide to reallocate its storage somewhere else.
(you changed your code, now this is a hashmap, but the problem is the same, this container reallocates its storage when it needs to)

When that happens, the previous pointers are dangling!
This is not harmful until you actually use them to access memory (in the second loop).